# Following is a dynamic form code which can insert data by adding multiple inputs from user in row but I want it in column. How do I do it?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I downloaded the following code from internet. This code will add extra inputs from the user but it will create a new row in the database. I want this to be inserted in different columns of a row. How do I do it?

I have created fields for insertion in the Column.

```
<form name="add_name" id="add_name">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" 
class="form-control name_list" /></td>                               
<td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add 
More</button> 
</td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" 
value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var i=1;
$('#add').click(function(){
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
    $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
});

$('#submit').click(function(){      
    $.ajax({
        url:"name.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            $('#add_name')[0].reset();
        }
    });
});

});
</script>
```

And this is the name.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$number = count($_POST["name"]);
if($number > 1)
{
for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
{
    if(trim($_POST["name"][$i] != ''))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(namec) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name"][$i])."')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    }
}
echo "Data Inserted";
}
else
{
echo "Please Enter Name";
}
?>
```

Comment: in your query for insert, you have mentioned one column and for that you have given one value. If you need to insert in multiple column, then you need to add in insert query.

Comment: Can you please show me how? I tried `$sql= "INSERT INTO tbl_name(namea, nameb,namec,named) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name"][$i])."')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);`

Comment: I would like to suggest you that your approach is wrong, as there can be 'n' number of names may be entered by user, but your columns will be limited to some numbers. So please tell me that how much names a user can enter?

Comment: I already know that. This situation is different @Praveen Pasishetti

Comment: 4 is enough for me. I understand you but lets reject the extra insertion @anuj

Comment: for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++) this line make it to enter data into multiple rows rather than multiple columns, so how if you try just $_POST["name"][0],$_POST["name"][1],$_POST["name"][2],$_POST["name"][3] for 4 values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments, I am assuming that there will be 4 names max. You can do the work as below:-

```
<?php
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
 $number = count($_POST["name"]);
 $db_col_names = array('namea','nameb','namec','named');
 $names = array();

 if($number > 1)
 {
      for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
      {
           if(trim($_POST["name"][$i]) != '')
           {
                $names[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name"][$i]); //get all the values from from in an array
           }
      }
      $names = implode("','", $names); //make all the values as string to pass in insert query
      $db_col_names = array_slice($db_col_names, 0, $number); //slice the DB columns to the names length entered
      $db_col_names = implode("`,`", $db_col_names ); //make all the values as string to pass in insert query

      $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(`".$db_col_names."`) VALUES('".$names."')";
      mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

      echo "Data Inserted";
 }
 else
 {
      echo "Please Enter Name";
 }
?>
```

Hope this will do the work which you need. If any more modifications needed or any issue, do let me know in comments